# Why is penetration testing done (for the most part) on Linux only?

Tags: penetration-test

I've been looking into penetration testing to further my general IT knowledge (not looking at getting into comp security but i have a curiosity about it), i noticed that a lot of video tutorials use Linux however no-where does it state why Linux is used

Does Linux simply give you access to functions etc. that simply don't exist in Windows / Mac OSX?

Comment: This is a bad question. There are tons of commercial and open-source pentest-test tools for most of the popular OS. If you are not looking hard enough,  don't make such conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

This question is probably only going to get you opinion based answers, as there is nothing Linux can do which Windows, OSX, or any other operating system cannot do.  The only real reason we can give is that many of the tools which have been developed have been developed on Linux.  Some reasons the developers of those tools may have chosen linux include cost, familiarity of the environment, or a preference for open source software.